# Redirecting \write to and \input from lua variable

Tags: beamer, luatex, verbatim

Beamer manages frames with catcode-changing content by first writing the content of the frame to a .vrb file, then reading it again (several times, as needed, if I understand correctly).

In LuaLaTeX, I wonder if performance could be increased by storing the content in a lua variable instead, and how to achieve this.

This leads me to ask if/how it is possible to use callbacks to effectively redirect `\write`s and `\input` that beamer does to a lua variable.

The documentation of luatex does mention a process_output_buffer callback, but I cannot get my head around how to use it, considering the absence of a file number (I surely do not want the callback to intervene on all `\write`s, only those to `\beamer@verbatimfileout`).

The process_input_buffer seems to act symmetrically, although I have seen and used it on the tex file being compiled rather than on a file being `\input`ed (but that was when the callback was added with `luatexbase.add_to_callback`, luatexbase being a thing that actually does not appear anywhere in the documentation).

However this is less important, because once we redirected the `\write`s to a lua variable, it should suffice to replace the `\input{\beamer@verbfilename}` with eg. `\luadirect{tex.print(verbframecontent)}`.

Comment: luatexbase table is not in the luatex manual it is the interface used in latex (and optionally plain) in ltluatex.lua see `texdoc ltluatex`

Comment: there isn't a callback but you can redefine `\write` look how `shellesc` package defines `\write` to use `\directlua{os.exec` if given file stream 18.